What's that orange icon with person on it in desktop screen on Google Chrome?
I noticed the icon appearing on the desktop screen. I was curious.

What does that mean? Is this kind of hacker? Or was that me as a user?

Not sure,  but usually that head-and-shoulders icon denotes the default user image. If you personalize the OS, that image could be you!.

When you create a second user profile in Chrome, Chrome will start showing the profile icon with the avatar of the selected userprofile.
If you remove all but one profiles, the Chrome icon in the taskbar will revert back to the normal logo without icon.

When you click the Chrome icon with an avatar, it starts as the profile the orange avatar belongs to.
Chrome support multiple profiles, each of which has their dedicated history, passwords, etc.
